# UITableView increases memory

Tags: memory, tableview

I created an app with a tableview. It contains a list of names that are requested from an URL using JSON. However, when I keep scrolling up and down for a long while (I used the indexed list on the right to speed the process up a little) the memory keeps going up. I tested it only my device and kept track of the memory usage in xcode. When it reached about 50-60MB my iPhone restarted (didn't even see a crash in the log window :P).

My memory also keeps increasing when I keep going back and forward to the next view from the tableview (so by selecting the same cell all the time). But I'd first like to fix the tableview issue. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger voornaamTag = 1;
    NSInteger tussenvoegselTag = 2;
    NSInteger achternaamTag = 3;

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"xCell";

    NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *voornaamLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 8, 100, 40)] autorelease];
        voornaamLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        //voornaamLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        voornaamLabel.tag = voornaamTag;
        voornaamLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Segoe-Semibold" size:19];
        [voornaamLabel setNumberOfLines:1];

        UILabel *tussenvoegselLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 8, 100, 40)] autorelease];
        tussenvoegselLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        //tussenvoegselLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        tussenvoegselLabel.tag = tussenvoegselTag;
        tussenvoegselLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-Light" size:19];
        [tussenvoegselLabel setNumberOfLines:1];

        UILabel *achternaamLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 8, 100, 40)] autorelease];
        achternaamLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        //achternaamLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        achternaamLabel.tag = achternaamTag;
        achternaamLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-Light" size:19];
        [achternaamLabel setNumberOfLines:1];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:voornaamLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tussenvoegselLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:achternaamLabel];
    }

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSDictionary *personDictionary = nil;
    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
    {
        personDictionary = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        personDictionary = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }

    NSString *voornaam = [personDictionary objectForKey:@"voornaam"];
    NSString *tussenvoegsel = [personDictionary objectForKey:@"tussenvoegsel"];
    NSString *achternaam = [personDictionary objectForKey:@"achternaam"];

    UILabel *voornaamLabel = (UILabel *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:voornaamTag];
    [voornaamLabel setText:voornaam];
    [voornaamLabel sizeToFit];

    UILabel *tussenvoegselLabel = (UILabel *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:tussenvoegselTag];
    [tussenvoegselLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(voornaamLabel.frame.size.width + 21, 8, 100, 40)];
    [tussenvoegselLabel setText:tussenvoegsel];
    [tussenvoegselLabel sizeToFit];

    UILabel *achternaamLabel = (UILabel *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:achternaamTag];
    if ([tussenvoegsel length] != 0)
    {
        [achternaamLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(tussenvoegselLabel.frame.origin.x + tussenvoegselLabel.frame.size.width + 5, 8, 100, 40)];
    }
    else
    {
        [achternaamLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(voornaamLabel.frame.size.width + 21, 8, 100, 40)];
    }
    [achternaamLabel setText:achternaam];
    [achternaamLabel sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

FYI: Voornaam means first name, tussenvoegsel means second name, achternaam last name.